# how can i fix this issue "NameError: name 'f' is not defined" here is my function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

my code is having issues where I don't know how to define f so that my code can work properly. please help.

```
stopwords = []
try:
    f = open("https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js/blob/develop/src/config/stopwords.js", 'r')
    stopwords = f.read().split('\n')
except IOError:
    print('Problem opening file')
finally:
    f.close()
print('Sentence before stopwrods removed: \n', tokenized[51])
filtered = []
for t in tokenized:
    text = t[0]
    f_text = []
    for word in text:
        if word not in stopwords and len(word) > 2:
            f_text.append(word)
    filtered.append((f_text, t[1]))

print('\nSentence after stopwords removed: \n', filtered[51]
```

Comment: the problem is here: `finally: f.close()`. You cant close `f` if your `try` wasnt successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stopwords = []

try:
    f = open("https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js/blob/develop/src/config/stopwords.js", 'r')
    stopwords = f.read().split('\n')
except IOError:
    print('Problem opening file')
else:
    f.close()
print('Sentence before stopwrods removed: \n', tokenized[51])
filtered = []
for t in tokenized:
    text = t[0]
    f_text = []
    for word in text:
        if word not in stopwords and len(word) > 2:
            f_text.append(word)
    filtered.append((f_text, t[1]))

print('\nSentence after stopwords removed: \n', filtered[51])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `with` clause. It makes sure the file is closed in any case, if it is necessary. So in the code below the `except` clause is only used to print the error text.

```
stopwords = []
try:
    with open("https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js/blob/develop/src/config/stopwords.js", 'r') as f:
        stopwords = f.read().split('\n')
except IOError:
    print('Problem opening file')
print('Sentence before stopwrods removed: \n', tokenized[51])
filtered = []
for t in tokenized:
    text = t[0]
    f_text = []
    for word in text:
        if word not in stopwords and len(word) > 2:
            f_text.append(word)
    filtered.append((f_text, t[1]))

print('\nSentence after stopwords removed: \n', filtered[51]
```